# Dependency errors when releasing multi module .Net projects with NPanday and Jenkins

Tags: .net, maven, jenkins

I have some problems when trying to release a .Net project with NPanday and Jenkins.

My project structure is the following:

```
net_test (parent, with 2 modules)
  net_test_1
  net_test_2 (dependent of net_test_1)
```

When I try to release these using a regular maven command line with first

```
mvn release:prepare
```

and then

```
mvn release:perform
```

everything works fine. But when I try to relese the project using jenkins, the net_test_2 module says that it cannot resolve net_test_1 in the version I am trying to release. This is of course the case since it hasn't been built yet but since it is in the reactor, it will be built and the dependency shouldn't have to be resolved yet.

The error message is as follows

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building net_test_2
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [INFO] [compile:initialize {execution: default-initialize}]
[INFO] 2012-maj-18 10:48:44 npanday.PathUtil getDotNetArtifact
[INFO] VARNING: 
[INFO] NPANDAY-1005-0001: Error copying dependency com.apptus.dag:net_test_1:dotnet-library:1.0.1:compile File C:\.m2\repository\com\apptus\dag\net_test_1\1.0.1\net_test_1-1.0.1.dll does not exist
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.apptus.local/content/repositories/releases//com/apptus/dag/net_test_1/1.0.1/net_test_1-1.0.1.dll
[INFO] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.apptus.dag:net_test_1:dotnet-library:1.0.1' in repository releases (http://repo.apptus.local/content/repositories/releases/)
[INFO] 2012-maj-18 10:48:48 npanday.dao.impl.ProjectDaoImpl storeProjectAndResolveDependencies
[INFO] VARNING: NPANDAY-181-121:  Problem in resolving assembly: com.apptus.dag:net_test_1:dotnet-library:1.0.1:compile, Message = Unable to download the artifact from any repository
[INFO] 
[INFO] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Then, install it using the command: 
[INFO]     mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.apptus.dag -DartifactId=net_test_1 -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=dotnet-library -Dfile=/path/to/file
[INFO] 
[INFO] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[INFO]     mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.apptus.dag -DartifactId=net_test_1 -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=dotnet-library -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO]   com.apptus.dag:net_test_1:dotnet-library:1.0.1
```

I don't know if this is a problem with NPanday, the M2 release plugin for jenkins or something else.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the goals for prepare must be set to "install" at least. But this will be fixed in 1.5 (still not released).